# Question tagged training was closed as off topic

Tags: support, closed-questions, tags, close-reasons, on-topic-definition

Why was this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145645/records-of-daily-work-of-programmers) closed as off-topic?

It was tagged `training` and when you look at the definition of the tag `training`:

> You may use this tag when your question revolves around for example:
>   Where can I find materials to train for ... ? Asking which training
>   course is best for you is off topic or not constructive at best as the
>   answers will be equally valid and only apply to you.

you can see that my question is on-topic and wasn't asking for the "best" thing for me.

Comment: related discussion at MSO: [screencast and training tags on Stackoverflow and Programmers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130112/screencast-and-training-tags-on-stackoverflow-and-programmers)

Comment: @gnat As a closing person, you could tell why do you think that it's off-topic or was it only intuition?

Comment: actually I've been thinking between off-topic and not constructive - still am not sure which one fits better. Off-topic for "using effectively the tools like an editor..." (specific tools are for SO), not constructive for [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ "Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!")

Comment: @gnat OK, I tried to avoid shopping to ask for only the main site (and tag definition enables this) and I asked first on SO where it was heavy downvoted and deleted. I'm satisfied with the accepted answer, but nobody can write comments to this question and that's not good.

Comment: Crafting questions on SE is an art in itself. I'm surprised they haven't sold a book about it on Amazon, because it could fill a 300 page book!

Comment: @Zenph Asking questions on SE is a subset of asking questions. There are a few articles about asking questions on the Internet. I believe that a book about special SE restrictions could be created from posts on meta sites.

Comment: @xralf..book has a variable length. Please be more specific. How many pages? How big is the print? How many words? That should settle things? Anal enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the tag wiki says that you can use this tag for asking where to find resources, I don't think that's valid. [Stack Exchange sites are not search engines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128549#128549). What you are asking for is simply asking for external resources - the best place to do that is in the search bar of your favorite search engine.

It also sounds like you're asking for a list of things. [Stack Exchange sites are also not for generating lists of things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128561#128561).

Comment: Search engines aren't so good yet, to be able to answer such complicated query, so human knowledge makes better job here.

Comment: @xralf That doesn't change the fact that Stack Exchange sites are not the place for asking for resources or generating lists of things.

Comment: This is in contradiction with the `training` tag definition and I believe that before this purist movement the sense of the tag `training` was exactly such. I think that asking for one particular resource is useful for the community and it's not so difficult to ignore such questions for members who hate it.

Comment: And according to the points, you can see that many members welcome question asking for particular resource.

Comment: @xralf I'm not sure of the confusion. The definition of the training tag is incorrect and against the general rules of Stack Exchange. The number of up votes on a question don't matter. This question doesn't abide by the rules for a good question, therefore it gets closed.

Comment: I added this explanation to the tag definition.

Comment: The question seems to be asking if such a resource exists instead of a list of resources. I've edited the question a bit to clarify that, so perhaps we can consider reopening it?

Comment: @Rachel How is that different? It's still asking for a resource, not asking a question. The best tool to address the concern is still a search engine, not asking other people.

Comment: @ThomasOwens It's asking if something exists or not. Sometimes it's hard to get the search engine to give you the links you're looking for, particularly if you don't know the right keywords to use. Asking a group of software developers if something exists or not is a much more efficient and accurate than of just assuming the search engine isn't giving you results because there are none.

Comment: @Rachel And there are avenues for that. Chat comes to mind. Asking a question isn't the place.